# how to set up lock mode in firebase, so that only One person can change the data

Tags: angular, firebase, security, firebase-realtime-database

I built and ecommerce app, and it get's all it's data from firebase which I manually put there on a form a created to collect information and add to firebase, I recently learned that it is possible for anyone to delete or alter my data as my read and write rules are both true. how do I set it that only I can alter my data with the appropriate credentials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is in your statement "with the appropriate credentials".

You will first need to have that person sign in with Firebase Authentication. Once you've done that, they'll have a UID: a unique user ID within Firebase.

Once you know their UID, you can change the [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) of your database, so that only that one user can write data. In its simplest form that can be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth.uid === 'theUidOfTheOneUserWhoCanMakeChange'"
  }
}
```

This is quite a broad topic, so I recommend reading the docs I linked above, and this documentation on [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) for all Firebase products that support them.